# Call Swift enum case within same enum function

Tags: swift, enums, case

I'm trying to get my head around Swift enums and in doing so have taken myself off a tutorial track by trying to return a string from a function within the same enum...

```
enum topFiveBands: Int {
    case led_zeppilin = 1, queen, rush, pink_floyd, acdc

    func printRating() {
        print("The band \(???) has been ranked no.\(self.rawValue) of all time")
    }
}

var myFavBand = topFiveBands.acdc
myFavBand.printRating()
```

My code starts with a implicit assignment which lists the top 5 bands of all time (some of you may disagree with me on this..). Within the same enum I have a function which will print:

```
The band \(???) has been ranked no.\(self.rawValue) of all time
```

I've chosen `.acdc` so I'm looking for the function to return:

```
The band acdc has been ranked no.5 of all time
```

Whilst I can pull the rawValue (5) I can't seem to find a way to get the `acdc` into the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `self`:

```
func printRating() {
    print("The band \(self) has been ranked no.\(self.rawValue) of all time")
}
```

The `self` is the reference to its own value which is `acdc` in this case.

Comment: Both your and Emilio's answer worked as hoped. Thank you. Green tick given to Emilio though as I'm able to capitalise band names (blame the OCD in me :))

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `self`, I would advise against it because with `enum` names you have limitations, like having to use `pink_floyd`.

Instead I would recommend adding a `String` property that returns a display name depending on the value of the `enum`

```
var displayName: String {
    switch self {
    case .pink_floyd: return "Pink Floyd"
    case ...: // The rest
    }
}

func printRating() {
    print("The band \(displayName) has been ranked no.\(rawValue) of all time")
}
```